# Ubuntu 18.04 does not restore from hibernate on X1 Carbon

Tags: suspend, lenovo, thinkpad, hibernate

I purchased an X1 Carbon because it is supposed to be Ubuntu certified:
https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201712-26045/

50% of the time it fails to restore from hibernation.  This makes it useless and I lose all my work.  Please, please help.  I can't even tell why it fails.  It says it does s2disk before it hibernates, but just freezes on a back screen.

### Update

Is there some element of this that is transparently problematic?

```
+++ System Info
System         = LENOVO ThinkPad X1 Carbon 6th 20KH002KUS
BIOS           = N23ET59W (1.34 )
Release        = Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Kernel         = 4.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 6 09:33:07 UTC 2019 x86_64
/proc/cmdline  = BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-46-generic root=UUID=64f9d81d-0494-4f90-983e-5168b6420c6e ro resume=/dev/nvme0n1p4 no_console_suspend initcall_debug acpi.ec_no_wakeup=1 resume=/dev/nvme0n1p4 no_console_suspend initcall_debug acpi.ec_no_wakeup=1
Init system    = systemd v237
Boot mode      = UEFI
```

Comment: Note that it was certified for an OEM version of 16.04, not 18.04. This could indicate that the OEM resolved the problem in their custom build of the kernel, or that a regression in 18.04 caused the issue.

Comment: Sometimes, it helps to have a small delay built into the resume functions of grub.  My grub command line looks like this:  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="resume=UUID=e1cd249f-f9b7-41e9-9406-8b50f4a306d5 resume_offset=1699840 resume_delay=5"`

Answer (score 2):

Try installing tlp Linux Advanced Power Management to try a workaround the issues of the kernel. This is not guaranteed to work but its worth a try. It also has some features tailored to thinkpads so it might improve battery life even more with a little digging on their site
You can install it using the command below:

```
   sudo apt install tlp tlp-rdw
```

to run it run the below command:

```
   sudo tlp start
```

Comment: I installed this, but it still restores to a black screen.  It's clearly "on" and it makes sounds when I plug and unplug my power cord, but there is no control or visual feedback of any kind.  All I can do is reboot.

Answer (score 2):

When all other hibernation Tips & Tricks fail, install [TuxOnIce](https://launchpad.net/~tuxonice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tuxonice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tuxonice-userui linux-generic-tuxonice
```

If suspend or resume does not work, take a look at `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` and `dmesg`, provide feedback on the tuxonice-devel@lists.tuxonice.net mailing list.

Having said the above, [never believe a random stranger on the Internet to install a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for), do your own due diligence and obviously a PPA with 1000s of happy users will be more safe than `ppa:maffia.it/botnet` with a few 100 users...

Comment: Saw your comment seeking help on this thread but I haven't used hibernation in decades due to many errors it can cause :( I concur with sage advice to never accept PPA Candy from strangers :) - from my phone with no @ pings.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is broken in 18.04. I've been experiencing this and I'm not alone.

I personally fixed by switching to ubuntu 18.10. it may not be LTS but good god an incredible number of things that don't work on 18.04 work on 18.10 and none of the things that work on 18.04 don't work on 18.10.

Comment: This is a helpful testimonial.

Comment: we're exactly one month away from ubuntu 19 anyways. if you want you can hold out one month more and get the added "LTS" bonus!

Comment: @tatso 19.04 is ***not*** lts

Comment: ok "stable". what I'm saying is a private user shouldn't care about LTS

Answer (score 0):

This is total superstitious magic, but through great trial and error, I've found that doing all of the below increases my chance of a successful hibernate:

- Make sure the power status (plugged/unplugged) is the same at the time of restart as it was during hibernate.
- Disconnect from wifi/network before hibernate.
- When you do get the black screen, wait 2 minutes.  Then press:

  - F1
  - Fn+F1
  - Ctrl+F1
  - Alt+f1

  Then wait 2 more minutes.  Often, it just turns on.

I have not done enough experimentation to know which is responsible, if any, but this is my ritual in absence of consistent computer behavior.