# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't wake up after suspension - Lenovo Y540 with NVIDIA RTX 2060

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, suspend

My Lenovo Y540 with NVIDIA RTX 2060 doesn't wake up properly after suspension. The computer seems to work as I can turn the volume up or down (and hear the a characteristic sound) but the screen is blank. I know that this issue was raised couple of times on this site, but neither of excisting solution, like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1041397/1016115) or updating kernel (I have 5.0.0-36-generic already) seems to work for me.

If there is any console output that could enhance the quality of this question, I'll be happy to update.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1126269/344926) yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this driver problem 1 year ago.

As per https://www.geforce.com/drivers. Version: 440.36 is the recent stable and recommended driver avalible for NVIDIA RTX 2060.

Recent packages are avalible in graphics-drivers/ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440
```

If problem continues, then try switch to nvidia-dkms-440

```
sudo apt install dkms nvidia-dkms-440
```

For me nvidia-dkms-440 working well for 940mx. This should solve your problem.

Comment: This worked, but with minor tweak: I had to input `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440` instead of `sudo apt install nvidia-440` - it appears that the syntax has changed.

Answer (score 0):

you must install nvidia driver and reboot your laptop. I had same problem today and fixed it by installing nvidia driver

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, try first installing drivers in Software & Updates app. And select "Using NVIDIA drive rmetapackage from nvidia-driver***" and pick the highest number.

If the issue persists, then you should update to newer version of the Nvidia drivers perhaps through PPA.